# How can I use Bash `read` to assign command line arguments with spaces?

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I have a Bash function that takes multiple command-line arguments:

```
make_pizza() {
  echo "Pizza(sauce=\"$1\", crust=\"$2\", cheese=\"$3")"
}
```

It doesn't matter in this simple example, but in a longer script, naming the variables is good coding practice:

```
make_pizza() {
  sauce="$1"
  crust="$2"
  cheese="$3"
  echo "Pizza(sauce=\"$sauce\", crust=\"$crust\", cheese=\"$cheese")"
}
```

This makes the rest of the script more readable, and allows easily refactoring the order of the arguments.

It's quicker and (arguably) cleaner to do the variable assignment in one line, like so:

```
make_pizza() {
  read -r sauce crust cheese <<< "$@"
  echo "Pizza(sauce=\"$sauce\", crust=\"$crust\", cheese=\"$cheese")"
}
```

This particular `read` design makes it even simpler to insert or reorder the arguments later (i.e., there's no renumbering required). Unfortunately, it breaks on arguments with spaces:

```
$ make_pizza "Grandma's marinara" "Chicago-style" "stilton"
Pizza(sauce="Grandma's", crust="marinara", cheese="Chicago-style stilton")
```

Is there a compact, one-line idiom like this that works with arguments containing spaces?

(EDIT: This is a toy example to illustrate the problem. The question is about how to compactly parse numbered arguments into named variables, not about code golf with this particular example.)

Comment: Do not try to parse the arguments. Just use the already parsed values. If you want to put the code in one line, use two semicolons. Use `local` to declare local variables in functions.

Comment: Since you know what parameter holds what kinda pizza topping, you can just use `$1` etc in the `echo` right?

Comment: The assignments can be consolidated on to one line, unless your real objection is to using `$1` et al. instead of `$@`.

Comment: @0stone0 Just using `$x` works fine for simple cases like this toy example, but in general naming the variables makes the rest of the script more clear and more maintainable.

Comment: Have you considered writing a `name_args` utility function?

Answer (score 2):

This is a one-liner:

```
$ make_pizza() { printf "Pizza(sauce=%s, crust=%s, cheese=%s)\n" "$@"; }
$ make_pizza "Grandma's marinara" "Chicago-style" "stilton"
Pizza(sauce=Grandma's marinara, crust=Chicago-style, cheese=stilton)
```

Comment: This works great for this toy example; my question is more general, about compact parsing of numbered arguments into named variables.

Comment: @Sasgorilla As I have said: you do not want to do this. Type "help read" in your terminal and realize, that Bash's ability to parse anything is very limited. Whenever you have the chance to avoid parsing, take it eagerly. If your are looking for an unobtainable challenge the following list of failures may be a starting point: [How to split a string with quotes (like command arguments) in bash?](https://superuser.com/questions/1066455/how-to-split-a-string-with-quotes-like-command-arguments-in-bash)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store your variables in one line, you may use the semicolon between each assignment:

```sh
make_pizza() {
  sauce="$1"; crust="$2"; cheese="$3"
  echo "Pizza(sauce=\"$sauce\", crust=\"$crust\", cheese=\"$cheese\")"
}
```

You can also put everything in a single line, using more semicolons:

```sh
make_pizza() { sauce="$1"; crust="$2"; cheese="$3"; echo "Pizza(sauce=\"$sauce\", crust=\"$crust\", cheese=\"$cheese\")"; }
```

If you simply want to echo but you don't really care about storing the arguments into variables:

```sh
make_pizza() { echo "Pizza(sauce=\"$1\", crust=\"$2\", cheese=\"$3\")"; }
```

Comment: Just assigning everything in one line with semicolons works but still gets a little clunky with 5+ variables. The `read -r foo bar baz` syntax also makes it easier to reorder the variables or insert one later without refactoring the rest of the script (which happens a lot).

Comment: To be fair, if your function has 5+ arguments stored in 5+ names variables, it will probably be clunky one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

An exercise in syntactic sugar -

```
$: pizza(){ local sauce=0 crust=1 cheese=2 pizza=( "$@" )
  echo "sauce is \"${pizza[sauce]}\", cheese is \"${pizza[cheese]}\", crust is \"${pizza[crust]}\"."
}

$: pizza "Sicilian Marinara" "deep dish" "mozzarella & romano"
sauce is "Sicilian Marinara", cheese is "mozzarella & romano", crust is "deep dish".
```

Arguments are still order dependent this way, though.

Answer (score -1):

> How can I assign command line arguments with spaces?

You have the values in positional arguments already - just use them.

```
sauce="$1"
crust="$2"
cheese="$3"
```